# iText7 html2Pdf convert error - specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert HTML file to PDF with iText7 add-on html2Pdf. I have this code and always when I call method `ConvertToPdf` program failed with error: **specified method is not supported**. 
I'm trying it with valid trial licence key. I also try it without `ConverterProperties` and the result was the same. 
Is there another way how to create PDF from HTML file with iText ?

```
 ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
            props.SetMediaDeviceDescription(new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.ALL));
            LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(@"C:\Users\blah\kerz.xml");
            string ppa = @"C:\Users\blah\Desktop\html\index.html";
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileInfo(ppa), new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\blah\Desktop\html\a.pdf"),props);
```

[image]

Comment: The `itext.layout.dll`where the error occurs isn't part of the pdfHTML add-on (`pdf2html`); it's part of the core iText library. The problem you experience is typical when you combine versions of iText core and pdfHTML that aren't compatible. Check the [compatibilty matrix](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). For instance: pdfHTML 2.0.x won't work with iText Core 7.0.y.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for reply, I checked versions in my project and compatibilty matrix and versions should be compatible. I have installed iText7 Community ver 7.1.2 and iText pdf2Html ver 2.0.2.

Comment: OK, then that's not the cause. Unfortunately, I don't have a C# environment, only a Java environment, and everything works well in Java. I know that no code is published on Nuget unless it has passed all QA tests, so I am sure that the HTML to PDF conversion works, but you'll have to find a C# developer to help you out (or use Premium support from iText Software).